# OleDbConnection не получает команды извне

Tags: c#, ado.net

Написал класс по примеру из https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135321/how-to-create-a-method-in-a-class-that-would-connect-to-my-database-on-calling

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CntDscnt
{
    class Base_Class
    {
        public List<string> cnctVars = new List<string>();

        public OleDbConnection FlCnctn()
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();

            string DBPath = cnctVars[0];
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DBPath ;
            return con;
        }
        public OleDbDataReader FlReader()
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table1";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, FlCnctn());
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            return reader;
        }

        public void readDB()
        {
            while (FlReader().Read())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine((FlReader().GetInt32(0)) + " val");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Вызываю из класса формы

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CntDscnt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Base_Class base_Class =  new Base_Class();
        OpenFileDialog OPF = new OpenFileDialog();

        private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OPF.Filter = "accdb files (*.accdb)|*.accdb|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (OPF.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                label1.Text = OPF.FileName;
                base_Class.cnctVars.Add(OPF.FileName);
                //_Base_Class.cnctVars.Add(_OpenFileDialog.FileName);
                //
            }
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base_Class.FlCnctn().Open();
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base_Class.FlCnctn().Close();
        }

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(base_Class.FlCnctn().State);
        }

        private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base_Class.readDB();
        }
    }
}
```

Если вызывать в теле метода открыть соединение, то оно открывается и у возвращаемого OleDbConnection state == Open

```
public OleDbConnection FlCnctn()
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();

    string DBPath = cnctVars[0];
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DBPath;
    con.Open();
    return con;
}
```

А если вызывать так

```
base_Class.FlCnctn().Open();
```

то ничего не вызывается, но и компилятор не ругается, хотя State показывает при таком обращении правильно

```
Debug.WriteLine(base_Class.FlCnctn().State);
```

Вопроос то вот в чем, как правильно вызывать-то? В моем конкретном случае...

Comment: "а если вызывать ... то ничего не вызывается" - ??

Comment: Ваш метод `FlCnctn` _каждый_ раз возвращает _новое_ соединение. То есть вы открываете одно соединение, а читать потом пытаетесь с помощью другого, неоткрытого.

Comment: Вот блин, а . Опять я к этому и пришёл, только другим способом, только начинаю прогить на c# вот не пойму никак как обратиться к этому потоку или как он называется, как вообще это правильно сделать?

Comment: Igor, вызываться то что- то вызывается, только стэйт не меняется, как сказал Petrov, вызывает Ся каждый раз новое соединение, вот и думаю, как сделать так чтобы создавать соединение и закрывать ну и читать писать в него

Comment: все, разобрался